# How to use HTML entities in an SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

In a **SQL 2005 Report Server Project**, how do you put an HTML entity (such as & or Δ) in the value of a column's header Textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for those 2 symbols you can simply copy and paste.

Comment: That's too easy! I'll try it when I get back to work tomorrow.